# python regex find all single qutoes inside single quotes

Tags: python, regex, single-quotes

can you help me with regex to find all single quotes inside single quotes?

IE

```
'sinead o'connor','don't don't','whatever'
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your string was separted by comma.

```
re.sub(r"\b'\b", "''", s)
```

or

```
(?<=[^,])'(?!,|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lE1kB6/1)

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "'sinead o'connor','don't don't','whatever'"
>>> re.sub(r"\b'\b", "''", s)
"'sinead o''connor','don''t don''t','whatever'"
>>>
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, thanks for reposnse. Do you know how to build regex which will find all single quotes between single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this even without regex:

```
>>> string = "'sinead o'connor','don't don't','whatever'"
>>> string = string.replace("'", "''")
"''sinead o''connor'',''don''t don''t'',''whatever''"
>>> string.strip("'")
"sinead o''connor'',''don''t don''t'',''whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'[\w|\s]*([']*)[\w|\s]*'
```

Check this on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bV4bL9/3)